# Is there a way to find the most adapted NN?

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a NN that uses one or two time series to predict the value of another one, using history. For example, in the next graph :

- **Blue** is the input
- **Orange** is the predicted output
- **Green** is the expected (real) output

[image: Example]

I already build a LSTM NN (`tensorflow` in python) with these layers :

- LSTM
- Dropout
- Dense
- Dropout
- Dense

I made a small loop that help me to detect best hyper-parameters (batch and buffer size, percentage of dropout,... event history) using `sklearn`'s `ParameterSampler`. I'm also using `RMSprop` (default value) as optimizer.

I was wondering if there is a way to know if my NN is adapted to my case:

1. Is the layer's composition and organization correct ?
2. Should I use something else ? GRU, NTM, etc.
3. Is there a better optimizer for my case ?

Comment: Regular dropout does not really work on time-series models https://medium.com/@bingobee01/a-review-of-dropout-as-applied-to-rnns-72e79ecd5b7b

Comment: The main way to quantify how good your model is to compute the metrics of interest on a validation and test dataset. This can be RMSE or MAE, or something more custom